# How can I fetch data only once with render?

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to fetch data only once at the beginning of the rendering, I'm trying to use **start** variable to control in case I need to fetch again

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [start, setStart] = useState(true);

const getData = async () => {
    console.log('getting data');
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    setData(res.data);
    setStart(false);
};

let count = 0;

useEffect(() => {
  if (start === true) {
    getData();
    console.log('Render: ', count);
    count++;
  }, [start])
```

count is just to count the renderers, and I'm getting more than one, always, even without dependencies in the useEffect hook I get 2.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using `<StrictMode></StrictMode>` around your app? It renders each component 2 times. Also some parent component may rerender.

Comment: Hei, Vladyslav, yes I'm using StrictMode and removing it solved the issue with the double render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many different options:

- first of all - if you will create useEffect with empty array of dependieces it will be called one, but please
- you can store in state that component has not been initliazed and data was not loaded
- you can use https://github.com/streamich/react-use - there is useEffectOnce or useMount

EDITED--------

BTW. regarding count === 2 that part of code looks ok, I guess that you mount and unmount that component then it will be recreated from the scratch

Comment: Hei, Grzegorz, thank you for your answer, I just checked the link and it has a lot of useful resources. Thank you. I still need to define some logic, cause it's a game that needs to fetch some data, and if the player wants to restart, it should refetch, but still working on that